# How to accept shorter user input into Element UI DatePicker?

Tags: vuejs2, datepicker, element-ui

In an existing code base the ElementUI and Vue2 packages got updated. The users are relying on what looks to be unintended behavior from the outdated DatePicker UI component.

The date is visually formatted as `30/01/2022` in the input field of the DatePicker elements.
To speed up typing users were entering `30012022` into the field instead. This behavior disappeared after the updates. Only entering the date with the / separator gets accepted.

How do I overwrite the vendor methods of the ElementUI Date Time component to ease the input validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gif shows the behavior of entering partial dates]

Replacing validation can be done by wrapping the el-date-picker into your own component. The trick is to use `$nextTick` inside `mounted()` and then access the method you want to replace through a *reference* on the wrapped component.

A small code example of the .vue file using TypeScript:

```
<template>
  <el-date-picker
    ref="customDatePicker"
    :type="type"
    :size="size"
    :value="value"
    :clearable="clearable"
    :format="displayFormat"
    :value-format="valueFormat" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import moment from 'moment'
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

type PickerType = 'year' | 'month' | 'date' | 'dates' | 'datetime' | ' week' | 'datetimerange' | 'daterange' | 'monthrange'
type Size = 'large' | 'small' | 'mini'

@Component
export default class RexDatePicker extends Vue {
  @Prop()
  readonly value: any

  @Prop({ type: String, default: 'small' })
  readonly size!: Size

  @Prop({ type: String, default: 'date' })
  readonly type!: PickerType

  @Prop({ type: String, default: 'yyyy-MM-dd' })
  readonly valueFormat!: string

  data() {
    return {
      clearable: this.$attrs.clearable !== 'false'
    }
  }

  get displayFormat() : string {
    if (this.type === 'year') {
      return 'yyyy'
    }
    return 'dd/MM/yyyy'
  }

  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      var elPicker: any = this.$refs.customDatePicker
      if (this.type === 'date' || this.type === 'daterange') {
        // inject custom date input behavior
        const originalParseFunction = elPicker.parseString
        elPicker.parseString = function (value) {
          value = expandNumbersToDate(value)
          return originalParseFunction(value)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}

function expandNumbersToDate(value) {
  // expects String, Date or an Array of those two
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object String]') {
    var currentMonth = moment().format('MM')
    var currentYear = moment().format('YYYY')
    value = value.replace(/^[^\d]*(\d{2})[^\d]*$/, `$1/${currentMonth}/${currentYear}`)
    value = value.replace(/^[^\d]*(\d{2})(\d{2})[^\d]*$/, `$1/$2/${currentYear}`)
    value = value.replace(/^[^\d]*(\d{2})\/?(\d{2})\/?(\d{4})[^\d]*$/, '$1/$2/$3')
  }
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value = value.map(date => expandNumbersToDate(date))
  }
  return value
}
</script>
```